# backbonejs: can I use the initialize function to make a GET request for each new model?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, model

So as I understand it each model in backbone has a .fetch() method which makes a GET request to a provided url. Can this be used inside the initialize function to fill the model with data each time new Model() is called?

My use case is I want to display some random data from wikipedia articles... so I tried this.fetch() to try and pull in some JSON which I hoped to format but it seems it can't even log it to console.

```js
var Article = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    title: ''
  },
  urlRoot: 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=random&rnlimit=1&format=json',
  initialize: function () {
    this.fetch({
      success: function (res) {
        console.log(res.toJSON());
      },
      error: function(){
        console.log('could not initialize model');
      }
    });
  }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.new-card').on('click', function () {
    var article = new Article();
  });
});
```

hit the button, console reads

```
could not initialize model
```

Any thoughts on whats going wrong?

Comment: I get a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error. With a different `urlRoot` it works as expected http://jsfiddle.net/4fnxL1fz/1/

Comment: Yes, wikipedia does not allow CORS requests. I'm curious why you chose to not mention that you get that error?

Comment: Yeah, this question is not what it's asking. Yes, you totally can call `fetch()` from `initialize`. The real problem here is the [Same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), which disallows ajax requests to another domain.

Comment: Thanks all, this is very useful. where would this error message appear, I didn't mention it because I hadn't spotted it but it would have spared me a lot of stress.

Comment: @aaaaargZombies you can see such error in developer tool, which can be opened by pressing `F12`